# Restore position after undo in vim

Tags: vim

I'm currently writing a vim script that runs my code through the `gofmt` linter. Once I have the output from the command, I run the following.

```
let view = winsaveview()
1,$d
undojoin | call setline(1, gofmt_output)
call winrestview(view)
```

This works great, however, when the user presses <kbd>u</kbd> to undo, the file scrolls back to the top. Is there a way around this? Below is a gif of the behavior.

[image: Pressing undo after running :GoFmt jumps to top of file]

Comment: No, I don't think there's a way around it. Vim recognizes that all lines got deleted, so the only "safe" position is the first line.

Comment: Is there a better way I could be replacing the buffer contents that doesn't involve such a side effect?

Comment: You could compare original lines with the updates in `gofmt_output` and determine the first line that's different. Then, only `:delete` from there, and `setline(first_diff_line, gofmt_output[(first_diff_line - 1) : -1])`

Comment: I use the code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/docwhat/2973488) to achieve something similar when running commands like `gg=G`. It's pretty handy but I'm not sure if you'd be able to work it into your script.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack I just found that seems to be working somewhat.
All I do is to make a bogus, noop change on the current line
before I replace the buffer contents.
In my case I simply read the new content from a file so it looks like this:

```
  let winview = winsaveview()
  :s/$//
  :%!cat /tmp/.vimfmtnew
  call winrestview(winview)
```

The `s/$//` bit is the noop change on the current line, and `:%!cat /tmp/.vimfmtnew` replaces the whole buffer with my tmpfile.

My theory about this is that vim collapses all changes from my function into a single undo action and puts the cursor position to the first action's first changed line. This now happens to be an action where my cursor was when I called the function so this puts the cursor onto the correct line.

It's not perfect though:
if you have the same buffer open in a split view,
the unfocused split views will still reset on undo/redo.
I think the correct solution is this:
diff the old and new content
and only replace the changed lines.
I think that would retain the positions in the split views too
but it's a bit more effort to implement this nicely.
(Doing the replace from the first changed line doesn't always work for me
because I use goimports as my formatter and that can change lines near the beginning too so that would almost be equivalent to a full replace.)